# Phrase synonymous to "a general understanding"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms, phrase-requests

I am writing a goal where I would like to replace the phrase "a general understanding" with something synonymous.

The whole line reads:

> Writes clean and concise code that reflects **a general understanding** of the codebase and its external modules.

Alternative that I don't like:

> Writes clean and concise code that reflects **efforts to understand** the codebase and its external modules.

I am looking for a similar phrase which uses an alternative to "understanding" with a positive adjective describing it.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. This is out of scope (writing advice) per the [FAQ]. You are welcome to edit the question, to reframe it so that it is not a writing advice request. Also please add the results of research you undertook before asking here. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd There was an earlier Q on phrase-requests similarly objected to. Phrase-requests cannot be off-topic *per se*.

Comment: I realise this might be part of a list or some other non-prose structure, but "Writes" is missing a subject. Putting it in the imperative, "Write", would sound better.

Comment: @deadly, thank you for the tip; slang and misuse have muddied my English usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the phrase **superficial understanding**, or simply, **general insight into a particular subject**.

Comment: Given the usually negative connotation with superficial -- [see 2.c](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial), I don't think that would bode well with my supervisor. I do like using the term insight.

Comment: @le_garry Then I think *general insight* should be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you. Final: `Writes clean and concise code that displays a growing insight of the codebase and its external modules.`

Comment: @le_garry That sounds pretty positive. Great choice of the adjective *growing*. However, I suggest the preposition *into* to be used after *insight*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to qualify understanding as "general".  If you wrote

> Writes clean and concise code that reflects **an understanding** of the codebase and its external modules.

then this would have the exact meaning you want.

*e:* Please remember that if you think this answer is wrong, you should consider leaving a comment explaining *why*.  :)

Comment: While I could use `an understanding`, I would like to describe it somehow in a positive light.

Comment: What about **an understanding** is not positive?

Comment: The 30%-ness of it. I think OP wants it both ways. How about 'a working understanding'.

Comment: "Clean and concise" are virtues for both human and computer languages. I think ornamenting "understanding" works against both. I'd even argue with the implication that clean and concise necessarily reflects understanding. Why connect them? This seems stronger to me: "I write clean and concise code. I understand the codebase and external modules."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little informal but [gist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gist#English) could work:

> Writes clean and concise code that reflects the gist of the codebase and its external modules.